# intersectObjects not returning obj from OBJMTLLoader

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a object that I'm adding into my scene. I also have various other cubes in the scene. I'm using the following code to fire a Ray and see if I can detect a collision:

```
var ray = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position, vec);
var intersects = ray.intersectObjects( scene.children );
```

For some reason, the regular shapes (cubes) are detected, but the objects that loaded from the obj files are not.

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
loader.load( 'models/technicalTable1.obj', 'models/technicalTable1.mtl', function ( obj ) {

    obj.scale.set(0.4, 0.4, 0.4);
    obj.position.x = - roomWidth/2 + 100;
    obj.position.y = 36;
    obj.position.z = - roomLength/2 + 25;

    scene.add( obj );

}, onProgress, onError );
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the recursive flag to `Raycaster.intersectObjects()`.

```
var intersects = ray.intersectObjects( scene.children, true );
```

three.js r.70

Comment: Hey I actually tried that and it hasn't worked. Any other ideas?

Comment: if difficult, use [EventControls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28675875/threejs-how-to-pick-just-one-type-of-objects/28679672#28679672)

Answer (score -1):

It doesnt work because the OBJMTLLoader creates a Three.Group
The Group does not have a raycaster.intersectObjects
(I just finished tracing it down and it went to a non implemented function
This REALLY limits the the use of OBJ objects. 
I have tried JSON but since you can not load materials and have to create UVmap I find that I need a person that can 3D model or not be able to use the intersectObjects. 
Not sure if this is a bug