# ThreeJS – way to show one object by intersecting another

Tags: three.js, intersection, onmouseover

I try to write a ThreeJS interaction where the user hovers a sphere and a connected text object will show up. The problem is to show the connected text object with the intersected sphere so every sphere shows its own text.

For now I only could show the same text object for each intersected sphere. I think there's some code in the raycast section missing that picks the right text object.

```
//create textObjects and add to scene
var selectTitles = [];

for (var i = 0; i < numSpheres; i++) {
    var title = 'Title '+i;
    var textGeom = new THREE.TextGeometry( title, {size: 0.5,height: 0});
    var textMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x334455,transparent: true, opacity: 0});
    var titles = new THREE.Mesh( textGeom, textMaterial );

    group.add( titles );
    titles = selectTitles[i];
}

//onMouseOver
if (intersects[0].object != INTERSECTED) {
   INTERSECTED = intersects[0].object;

   // here 'titles' doesn't pick different text objects because of the missing 'intersected' connection

   new TWEEN.Tween(titles.material).to({opacity:1},350)
   .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Bounce.EaseOut).start();            
}
```

Comment: if difficult, use [EventControls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28675875/threejs-how-to-pick-just-one-type-of-objects/28679672#28679672)

Comment: EventControls looks good but does it really solve my problem? I don't hover the text object but the sphere. By hovering the sphere, the assigned text object shall be displayed. For me it looks like EventControls is another way of what I do actually. Maybe you can proove me wrong...

Comment: @AlmazVildanov : 
I implemented EventsControls but it doesn't works perfect. Is there a reason why item 0 is always pre-selected?
This is my code:
`EventsControls.attachEvent('mouseOver', function() { console.log(this.event.item + ' is select');});
`

Comment: `for ( var i = 0; i < numSpheres; i ++ ) {

var sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

EventsControls.attach( sphere );

}`

Comment: `EventsControls.attachEvent( 'mouseOver', function () {

var item = this.event.item;
selectTitles[ item ].visible = true; 

});`

Comment: The sphere attach is also in my code but this.event.item is always 0 so if I check the log for the mouseover object 0 is selected by default. This is a problem for me because this will show the first title object by default and not just by mouseover.

Comment: show all your code )

Comment: http://heineundpartner.de/test/js/minified/dots.js

Comment: xm, try to make it earlier:

 `var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial);
    EventsControls.attach(sphere);

    //line init
    var lineGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
...`

Comment: Doesn't make a difference. Did you check the console log for the 0?

Comment: This event (`EventsControls.attachEvent`) must be within the `init()`

Comment: it is. I don't use a init function but calling the init stuff globally..

Comment: remove `EventsControls.attachEvent ()` of the `animations ()`!

Comment: turned out as a result?

Comment: Don't know what you mean. EventControls.attachEvent is in the initial for loop.

Comment: @AlmazVildanov take a look in the current status of the code. It works well for the last (tenth) sphere (0 - 9) but the others don't unbind the visibility and the first (0) is always bind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I advise you to stick to the same order, much like in the examples on the site threejs.org:

```
// global variables
var camera;
var scene;
...

window.onload = function() {
    init();
    render(); //final output    
}

function init() {
...
}

function render() {
...
}
```

I took the liberty to alter your code. Here is the [result](http://neftek.legko.ufanet.ru/MyWebGL/heine/). Code [here](http://neftek.legko.ufanet.ru/MyWebGL/heine/index_files/dots.js).

Comment: Works beautifull, but now I have a problem with the recreation of the mesh. After the Mesh disappears i want it to generate completely new, but as you can see here it doesnt work like in my old script, because now the onclick function lies inside the init function, so i cant call it :D any ideas? This is how it looks like at the moment: [Show](http://heineundpartner.de/test) and here is the code [Code](http://heineundpartner.de/test/js/dots.js)

Comment: `EventsControls.detach( mesh );  EventsControls.attach( newMesh );`