# Is there any way to call a function when mouse click on a object in three.js?

Tags: 3d, three.js, mouseevent

I have searched on Google and many methods lose effectiveness under newer version of `three.js`. Is there any built-in method?

If not, is there any libraries for mouse events or short achieves?

Comment: There is threex.domevents: https://github.com/jeromeetienne/threex.domevents. but it does not seem to work with the latest three.js. It probably would not be too hard to fix though.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12800150/catch-the-click-event-on-a-specific-mesh-in-the-renderer

Comment: @WestLangley This great!

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12808987/4013790) help me. It is vaild.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28679672/4131583

Answer (score -1):

```js
<script>
  var button = document.querySelector("button");
  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("Button clicked.");
  });
</script>
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
<p>No handler here.</p>
```

Comment: READ THE QUESTIONS CAREFUL!